# Get sub site title that you have access to with REST API

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I followed codes sample [here](http://www.sharepointstuffs.com/rest-api-security-trimming-sharepoint-2013/) with security trim to get a list of sub site titles that user have access.

I got

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform or access this resource.

Is there a solution for this?  The users have read-only at the root site and contribute at subside.

Below is the codes:

```
http://site/_api/web/webs/?$select=title,effectivebasepermissions&$filter=effectivebasepermissions/high%20gt%2032
```

Answer (score 0):

If i run this as a Visitor on my root site I get

> Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

as well. So it is safe to assume that you need a higher permission to call this method.

I'd say that you need at least `manageWeb` permission to run it.

Answer (score 0):

"Webs" (whether in CSOM, REST APIs or server side code) always requires manageweb to run.

A possible solution might be to use the search API to list items of site type. For instance, a call like this:

```
https://server/_api/search/query?querytext=%27contentclass=%22STS_Web%22%27
```

would display webs. You would need to filter on the "ParentLink" property to get webs from a particular web.

The advantage of this is that it is security trimmed, so the user will only see what they have permission to see.